# Error using stem X must be same length as Y

Tags: matlab

im trying to find the even and odd part of the x array but it returns me error using stem, X must be same length as Y this is my code in matlab

```
close all;
clear all;
clc;

n1 = -5:1:5;
AM = 19390;
x = [1,9,3,9,0,1,1,9,3,9,0];
fun(x,n1);


function [sima,xr] = fun(t,x)  
      x_reverse = fliplr(x);% time reversal
      sima = 0.5*(x + x_reverse); %even component
      xr = 0.5*(x - x_reverse); %odd component
      subplot(3,1,1);
      stem(t,x);
      title('Your signal x')
      subplot(3,1,2); 
      stem(t,sima);
      title('Even part');
      subplot(3,1,3);
      stem(t,xr);
      title('Odd part');
end
```

Comment: `stem` is a plotting function so it requires both of its arguments to have the same dimensions.

Comment: yy i know that but how can i change it?

Comment: I did run your code in octave and it did not return any errors

Answer (score 0):

the inputs of `fun` are reversed.

where you write

```
fun(x,n1)
```

you should have

```
fun(n1,x)
```

this or reverse the order of each reference and value vectors for each `stem` inside `fun`.

Comment: nope unfortunately thats not it

Comment: is there some more code where null elements are removed? I run your code with both f(n1,x) and f(x,n1) and there's no such X Y mismatch when calling stem4

Comment: no there isnt, thats the whole code, ande what do you have as output?

Comment: I get the even / odd signals as expected.  When f() inputs crossed there's no even part , the even part is null because n1=[-5:1:5] has no even component When inputs crossed the plots pile up samples on fewer reference values, the t side of stem plots look shorter despite MATLAB does not return any X Y mismatch error, stem works ok. Have you translated f() from Python? PY vector indexing starts with 0, not 1.